# Which Html tags are not supported in Android's Html library?

Tags: android, html

I'm using Android's Html library to parse some styled JSON.  According to the library's doc, it says

> This class processes HTML strings into displayable styled text. **Not all HTML tags are supported.**

So, my question is:  which Html tags are not supported by this library?

Thanks and cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [HTML Tags Supported By TextView](https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)

> ```
> <a href="...">
> <b>
> <big>
> <blockquote>
> <br>
> <cite>
> <dfn>
> <div align="...">
> <em>
> <font size="..." color="..." face="...">
> <h1>
> <h2>
> <h3>
> <h4>
> <h5>
> <h6>
> <i>
> <img src="...">
> <p>
> <small>
> <strike>
> <strong>
> <sub>
> <sup>
> <tt>
> <u>
> ```

Comment: @dlucci accept the answer, if you are satisfied which will help others to refer

Comment: <h1>, <h2>, <font size="..."> are not working. I tried with Lolipop device